# MeterialDesign WPF PackIcon Binding Kind

Tags: c#, wpf, kind

I try to change the Kind of a Packicon programmatically.

Updated Question:

That's my code now:

I implemented the Interface INotifyPropertyChagned now:

```
public partial class OwnExtendedMessageBox : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Then I added these lines

```
    //property of Binding changed
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
```

Then I call it like that

```
        switch (MessageBoxIcon)
        {
            case OwnMessageBoxIcon.None:
                MessageBoxIconKind = PackIconKind.Box;
                break;
            case OwnMessageBoxIcon.Info:
                MessageBoxIconKind = PackIconKind.Information;
                break;
            case OwnMessageBoxIcon.Warning:
                MessageBoxIconKind = PackIconKind.Warning;
                break;
            case OwnMessageBoxIcon.Error:
                MessageBoxIconKind = PackIconKind.Error;
                break;
            default:
                MessageBoxIconKind = PackIconKind.Box;
                break;
        }

        OnPropertyChanged("MessageBoxIconKind");
```

WPF:

```
<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{Binding MessageBoxIconKind}" Foreground="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush}" ...
```

I also tryed it with a string, but it also doesn't worked

Comment: In my mind Kind is a string, have you tried to set a string like "Box", "Information". Binding a string

Comment: Yes i have tried to set a string, but it doesn't worked.

Comment: I'm not sure about the type (has it to be a string or an PackIconKind?). In any way, your code will never work: you have to raise a PropertyChange event to let the view (XAML) know you changed the PackIconKind property. You can see here how it works https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/explain-inotifypropertychanged-in-wpf-mvvm/

Comment: Right click on PackIconKind (an enumeration) and select definition.  You need to parse the enumeration like this : PackIconKind kind = (PackIconKind)Enum.Parse(typeof(PackIconKind), "Box");

Comment: @PiGi78: So I have to send an event, every time the value of a Binding changes?

Comment: I updated the question with INotifyPropertyChagned

Comment: The ticket is closed so I can't post a reply with an example, If you need it, let me know how can I send it to you